# Button Back Home in ActionBar of sample android not working

Tags: android, sdk

I m trying to implement settings sample activity from sample Android on Android Studio, after installing and starting the test settings activity, it is running correctly for some device :

- Samsung S2 with 4.1.2 ✅
- Nexus 5 with Android 5.0.1 ✅
- Samsung TabS2 with Android 5.1.1 ✘

```
@Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
                    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
        }
```

I don't know if this bug is related to Android sample **Or** to Samsung Tab S2 Device , I need to know how resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a log inside this method 
If it comes inside the method but doesn't work then it might be a device issue 
If it doesn't come inside the method then it might be an os issue (with all assumptions in place )

Perform this activity once and then we will solve the issue